# Why and How use 'op' in excel?

Tags: excel

**How use op in excel**

I need code calc(A,B,op) in excel, but I don't know "what is this 'op'" and how use it.
*Can you show me code*

Comment: Would it be « operator » such as + or - or * ? Much like rpn calculators? But you will find a thorough explanation in the Excel help of the function and its use as well as examples.

Comment: Where did you find this "op" you're asking about?

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you want to calc?
It does not exist an CALC()-Function in Excel.
Is this a user defined function? If yes we need the vba-code to help.

Comment: I need to create a new funk. for the task

Comment: Create a custom Calc (A, B, Op) function of real type that performs one of the arithmetic operations on non-zero real numbers A and B and returns its result. The type of operation is defined by the whole Op parameter: 1 — subtraction, 2-multiplication, 3 — division, and the other values — addition. Use Calc to perform operations for data A and B defined by data integers N1, N2, N3.
priority task. And I need code

Comment: I finish. Thanks a lot everyone!!!

Comment: Please. If any of the comments or answers helped please vote and set the question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this Function in VBA Module1

```
Function calc(A As Long, B As Long, op As Integer) As Double

Dim dblResult As Double

    Select Case op
        Case 1
            dblResult = A - B
        Case 2
            dblResult = A * B
        Case 3
            dblResult = A / B
        Case else
            dblResult = A + B
    End Select

    calc = dblResult

End Function
```

in the Worksheet type =calc(1,2,1) 
Result will be -1

Best regards Chris

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, I find easy code for my problem (I did write)

```
Function calc(A,B,op)
If op= 1 then
Calc = A-B
End if
If op=2 then
Calc=A*B
End if
If op=3 then
Calc=A/B
End if
If op>3 then
Calc=A+B
End if 
End function
```